# Pointers are only used in algorithms concerning data-structure?

Tags: data-structures

From the point of view of writing pseudocode, I have never seen any algorithm making use of pointers except when writing algorithms about data-structure (like writing algorithms for linked list involve moving arrows which in essentially a pointers operation). So my hypothesis is that any use of pointers in pseudocode is implicitly taken care of when we choose the appropriate data structure for the algorithm and beyond that we don't need it. Agree or provide a counter example to my assertion.

Comment: Disagree. And what makes you think you can tell me what to do? Very rude.

Comment: I don't quite understand your philosophy and/or attitude, but do you accept merge sort as counter example?

Comment: How about two-pointer technique/approach?